# How do I generate a specific amount of random numbers?

Tags: python, loops, random, while-loop, numbers

I have to ask the user for a number and then produce exactly as many random numbers as specified by the user using a while loop.

```
import random

x = int(input("Write a number: "))
y = random.randint(0, 10)

while x != 0:
    print(y)
    y = random.randint(0, 10)
```

Comment: It's much better to check whether the input is a number rather than blindly using `int(input(...))`, which can fail with a runtime error if the input does not represent a number (e.g., if the user typed in the word "nonsense" or the string "xyz".)  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little modification to your code. 
You were not decreasing `x`

```
import random

x = int(input("Write a number: "))

while x != 0:
    y = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(y)
    x-=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop is going to spin forever because you never decrement `x`.  You could fix this by adding this to the body of your loop:

```
x -= 1
```

If you don't want it to spin forever when the user enters a negative number (since then it will decrease forever without ever hitting 0), you could change your `while` to:

```
while x > 0:
```

The more easy/standard/idiomatic way of doing this type of loop would be to use `for ... in range`:

```
for _ in range(x):
    print(random.randint(0, 10))
```

Comment: The last suggestion is easily the best way to do it. Beware though that using ```_``` as a dummy variable may break its use in interactive shells.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.choices` to select 10 values from a range.

```
x = int(input("Write a number: "))
values = list(random.choices(range(11), k=x))
```

For a larger range, you would probably rather make repeated calls to `random.randint`.

```
values = [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out that a `for` loop is far preferable to a `while` loop here, but Sam Stafford beat me to it! The list comprehension solution is also good.

I know your code is just an example, but those variable names are really poor, be careful. Anyway, here is a `numpy` solution, it might come in handy some day!

```py
import numpy as np

num_to_gen = int(input("Choose how many random numbers to generate: "))

rand_nums = np.random.randint(low=0, high=11, size=num_to_gen).tolist()

print(rand_nums)
```